# Runtime Exception BC30456 InitializeCulture in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have an ASP.NET WebForms solution that is composed of 5 VB.NET projects (1 WebForms project with 4 class library projects). Often, when I make changes to the code and Build the project and launch it from Chrome, I receive the following exception:

```
System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005): D:\myprojectfolder\AccSubManage1.aspx(1): error BC30456: 'InitializeCulture' is not a member of 'ASP.accsubmanage1_aspx'.
at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String virtualPath, String path)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

If I then go back to VS 2012, run "Clean Solution", and Build again, everything then works properly. In other words, the Clean and Build seems to resolve the problem, but I can't figure out why.

Also note, running "Rebuild All" doesn't resolve the problem unless I also run Clean Build before the Rebuild All.

Any ideas?